# Vim: Split one file into multiple files based on row count

Tags: windows, vim

I have a text file with 5,000 rows.  I need to split it into files with no more than 99 rows each.  Can I do this with vim?  If not, what are my other options?

Comment: `man split` is your friend

Comment: I should have been more clear, I was looking for a way to do this in Windows with vim.

Comment: Do you have Cygwin? which brings many the Linux tools to windows, it has split.

Comment: @Rob - I don't but I'll check it out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you define a control variable:

```
:let i = 1
```

Then, you write lines 1 to 99 (inclusive) to a file named after the current value of the control variable, cut those line, and increment the control variable;

```
:exec "1,99w! chunk-" . i|1,99d|let i = i + 1
```

Repeat as many times as needed:

```
49@:
```

This should give you 50 files named `chunk-1` to `chunk-50`.

Since 5000 is not divisible by 99 you will be left with 50 lines. Write them to `chunk-51`:

```
:w chunk-51
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a tool called split :) that will do this for you

example:

```
  split -a 3 -d -l 99 my_big_file.txt big_file_chunk_ 

  -a 3 : says to use a unique 3 character suffix for each chuck file
  -d   : says make that suffix a number so 001 002 all the way to 999
  -l 99: split file by line and have 99 lines or less in each chuck.

  next are the source file name and if you want the prefix to use for each produced file.
```

This will create multiple files with at most 99 lines from the original named

```
   big_file_chunk_001
   big_file_chunk_002
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested).

```
let lines = getline(1,'$')
let nb_files = len(lines) / nb_rows
for i in range(0, nb_files)
    call writefile(lines[(i*nb_rows) : min([(i+1)*nb_rows-1, len(lines)-1])], 'chunk_'.i
endfor
```

or also

```
let lines = getline(1,'$')
while len(lines)
   call writefile(remove(lines,min([99,len(lines)-1])), 'chunk-'.i)
endw
```